# React Native - why padding does not work?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Why padding never works in React Native? I have 10px padding in the image and the text box below:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 75,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    image: {
        width: 107,
        height: 165,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor:'blue'
    },
    description: {
        padding: 20,
        margin: 10,
        fontSize: 15,
        color: '#656565',
        backgroundColor:'red'
    }
});
```

Result: 
[image]

Any ideas why? Did I miss something?

Comment: I think you can write padding:10px;

Comment: You don't use `px` in react native @Jainam.

Comment: That's not it. You don't have to write 10px, it's accepting a number only. So it's 10 only. And I think problem is -> you are trying to put padding on Text and Image components. As far as I know, you can put padding on View component only. Have you tried to wrap your Image and Text component in View that has padding? I think it should work like this: `<View style={styles.container}><View style={{padding: 10}}><Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: imageURI}} /></View><View style={{padding: 20}}><Text style={styles.description}>{description}</Text></View></View>`

Comment: @Run can you accept my answer, since I think it most adequately answers your question?

Answer (score 32):

Use this for padding:

```
function padding(a, b, c, d) {
  return {
    paddingTop: a,
    paddingRight: b !== undefined ? b : a,
    paddingBottom: c !== undefined ? c : a,
    paddingLeft: d !== undefined ? d : (b !== undefined ? b : a)
  }
}
```

In practice

```
<Text style={{...padding(10, 20, 10, 5), color: "black"}}>Some text</Text>
```

Comment: great snippet, this is exactly what I needed. Also, I was passing padding a string like '20px', which is totally wrong. Needs just plain numbers, like 20

Comment: @laukok If you found this useful, please select it as the answer

Comment: This one won't work with values like `padding(10, 0, 5)`. It will return `10, 10, 5, 10` although it should be `10, 0, 5, 0`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Great point. I've amended my answer to fix this.

Answer (score 7):

Android with React Native tends to not like padding, unless it has a border. A temporary fix would be to change all of your "paddingXXX" to "marginXXX" to get the approximate styling you want.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    marginTop: 75,
    alignItems: 'center'
},
image: {
    width: 107,
    height: 165,
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor:'blue'
},
description: {
    margin: 30,
    fontSize: 15,
    color: '#656565',
    backgroundColor:'red'
}
});
```

It's a really bad workaround, but I have yet to see a concise fix to it. As far as I know, there is an issue on the Git repo but hasn't been fixed yet.

Answer (score 5):

padding issue for android is fixed in react-native v0.31.0 version.
for more details you can go to react-natvie release changelog https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases

Comment: Glad to know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another factor to consider is flexbox being used everywhere. Flexbox can take away bottom padding from what I have found, so wrapping in another `View` might be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55724273/12962610 answer

improved version:

```
export const padding = (a, b, c, d) => ({
  paddingTop: a,
  paddingRight: b ?? a,
  paddingBottom: c ?? a,
  paddingLeft: d ?? b ?? a,
})
```

Comment: New to javascript and I was wondering why -- The nullish coalescing operator can be seen as a special case of the logical OR (||) operator. The latter returns the right-hand side operand if the left operand is any falsy value, not only null or undefined. In other words, if you use || to provide some default value to another variable foo, you may encounter unexpected behaviors if you consider some falsy values as usable (e.g., '' or 0).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55724273, but can be done in a more concise manner with default arguments.

```
/**
 * Padding utility function that mimics padding syntax in web
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding
 */
export function padding(
  top: number | string | null,
  right: number | string | null = top,
  bottom: number | string | null = top,
  left: number | string | null = right
) {
  return {
    paddingTop: top ?? undefined,
    paddingRight: right ?? undefined,
    paddingBottom: bottom ?? undefined,
    paddingLeft: left ?? undefined,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for padding:

```
<View style={styles.textPadding}>
        <Text>balablabla</Text>
 </View>
```

```
textPadding: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        backgroundColor: "#FFA679",
        paddingVertical: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        textAlign: "center"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Padding in react native only accepts a number and not any other character.

Eg:

```
    <TextInput placeholder="Enter Text" style={{padding: 30}} />
```

Comment: And it doesn't answer the question. OP used `padding: 10` and `padding: 20`. Is it supposed to be a comment on [@Jainam's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690207/react-native-why-padding-does-not-work#comment60968964_36690207)?

Comment: Incorrect, padding can be of types `Number` or `String`, see https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#paddingtop for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text>
{` ${description} `}
</Text>
```

Adding space before and after like above helped me in most cases. Very helpful when you have nested 'Text' tags.

Answer (score 0):

If You are having issues and using `margin` is **not** an option, consider replacing `View` with `Button` or some other component that fixes the problem for You.

I am using [ReactXP](https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/) and for some reason, using `Styles.createButtonStyle` with ReactXp's `Button` worked, and `Styles.createViewStyle` with `View` did not.

Answer (score -2):

I have solution for your problem. Try this:

```
<Text>
  <View style={{padding: 20, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
    <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Description</Text>
  </View>
</Text>
```

Comment: `Text` should contain only `Text` elements, not `View`s.

Comment: Text can't contain View element