# React-Native's padding difference for Android vs iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

The problem when I use padding style it's a difference on Android - iOS

```
<Content  style={{padding: '7%'}}>
```

how can I take it in the same style

[image: the image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690207/react-native-why-padding-does-not-work might be able to help you

Comment: show more code.

Answer (score 5):

React native is unitless. It means that the value of 7% is not a valid value in this case. you should use a static value like 7 or 20 or you can use the `Dimensions.get('window').width` to get the width of page and use this to set some attributes. your code will be like this:

```
let windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width

<Content  style={{padding: windowWidth*7/100}}> // equal to 7%
```